# Combining Sinusoidal waves

Tags: trigonometry

Is there a general way to add sinusoidal waves? I'm trying to covert the following expression

$A_1 \cos(x+y)+A_2\sin(x-y)$

into

$A_3\cos(z)$ where $z$ is a function of $x$ and $y$

Comment: What do you mean by one wave? As you already have two variables, namely $x,y$?

Comment: I mean something of the form $Acos(z)$, if it is possible

Comment: Where $z$ is a function $f(x,y)$? If yes, please update your question accordingly.

Comment: Yes, I am not sure if it is possible but I want to convert it to that

Comment: Using [Euler's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula#Relationship_to_trigonometry) might help.

Comment: I think $A_3$ would also need to be a function of $x,y$, otherwise this would not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general when you add two sinusoidal waves together, the result is not necessarily a sinusoid.

In places where it is defined, the function $z=f(x,y)$ is just setting your two expressions equal together and solving for $z$:
$$
z = \arccos \big (\frac{1}{A_3}(A_1 \cos(x+y) + A_2 \sin(x - y)\big )
$$

If $A_3 \ge (A_1+A_2)$, then the input to $\arccos$ will be $\in [-1,1]$ and $z$ is defined.

However it is misleading to think that $cos(f(x,y))$ is a sinusoid (plane wave) of $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a simpler example, $A_1 \cos(x)+A_2\sin(x)$, is it possible to write this as $A_3 \cos(x)$? No, because $\sin$ and $\cos$ are linearly independent functions and you are attempting to say $\cos$ is sufficient to span the space of all their linear combinations.

In special cases, yes, e.g. take $A_1=0$ or $A_2=0$.